# How to fill empty cell values randomly which are sum of the last cell value?

Tags: python-3.x, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a value in 11th cell as 35. From 1st cell to 10th cell is empty. I want to fill 1st cell to 10th cell randomly and its sum should be equal to to 11th cell as per in figure. Cell 1 to 5 should have the values between (0-2) and Cell 6 to 10 should have the values between (0-5). Rows 1,2 and 3 filled by manually. I need formula for row 4 which satisfies the conditions and sum should be equal to 20. Guide me the formula in excel, libre-office calc or python. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the task is not very clear (in fact, why not just fill ten cells with the value 2 and get the desired 20?).

However, the task is not very difficult to solve: The first five cells are filled with `=RANDBETWEEN(0;2)`.

When calculating each next value, you are guided by the already accumulated sum of the previous cells `SUM($A1:E1)` - that is, fill the next four cells with

`=MIN(RANDBETWEEN(0;$K1-SUM($A1:E1));5)`

The tenth cell is calculated as the difference between the expected number and the already accumulated sum of the nine previous cells `=K1-SUM(A1:I1)`.
Your screenshot does not show the column names and row numbers - I gave formulas for the range **A1:K1**, you should adjust them according to your data.